# VS2015 throw caught exception within DebuggerStepTrough?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded my VS2013, and the same code has a different behavior in debug mode.

In VS2013, I was having the debug breaking on exception I got.

Some of them that might happens and are handled were put in Try-catch block with a DebuggerStepTrough:

Example:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
private void DoSomething(){
    try{
        throw new InvalidOperationException();//Obviously in my case, it's not a throw exception here but a method
    }catch(InvalidOperationException){
        //log something & handling this case
    }
}


private void SomeEntryPoint(){
    DoSomething();//In VS2015 I got the debug breaking here. In VS2013 I don't
}
```

I was not having this behavior in VS2013. Is there a way to avoid it?

(I've the "Just My Code" enabled)

Comment: In VS 2015 the code is running without any breaking on exception.

Comment: What do your exception settings look like? `DEBUG > Exceptions...` (`Ctrl+Alt+E`)

Comment: @test `Debug > Exceptions` doesn't exists anymore on VS2015. In the `Exception Settings` window, I've the default checkbox(I did `Restore Defaults` on the exception settings window).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, the behavior you described is a result of a new [performance improvement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/23/performance-improvement-when-debugging-net-code-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx) that was introduced in the Visual Studio 2015. The new feature  greatly reduces debugging overhead of processing clr exceptions thrown and caught within non-user modules (With Just My Code enabled).

Unfortunately, in an oversight, exceptions thrown and caught within functions with [DebuggerHidden], [DebuggerNonUserCode], and/or [DebuggerStepThrough] attributes are no longer treated as if they were thrown and caught within non-user code - the debugger essentially ignores those attributes with regard to exceptions in Visual Studio 2015 (Step filtering and Call stack filtering still work the same as they did in Visual Studio 2013).

The bad news is that there is no good way to restore the previous version's behavior for this scenario. There are 2 possible options:

1. Target your application to use .net framework version < 4.0
2. Refactor your code such that the functions/classes with those debugger attributes are in a different module and build that module optimized and/or without symbols.

The good news is that the Visual Studio debugger team has acknowledged the issue and will provide a workaround in the next update for Visual Studio 2015.

**Update**

The workaround for this issue is available in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and is detailed in the [Using the DebuggerNonUserCode Attribute in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/12/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/) blog post.

For those who just want to know what to do. Run the following in a command prompt:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Debugger\Engine /v AlwaysEnableExceptionCallbacksOutsideMyCode /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Comment: Damn... We have to reinstall VS2013 meanwhile, we have too much exception coming(like TimeoutException when trying to connect to some devices that are not reacheable) that prevent us from doing any debugging... Do we have an idea when the next update will come? Do you have any link that indicate they will restore this behavior?

Comment: That really sucks that you have to reinstall VS 2013. And I am sorry to say that there is no indication when the next update will be and there is no public announcement that this issue will be fixed.

I will try to update this answer when the workaround is available publicly.

Comment: Anyway, at least it brings some answer to my management and you're the closest that I will be from an answer. But where have you found that the visual studio debugger team has acknowledged the issue?

Comment: @J4N you can disable first-chance exception handling for specific exception types (e.g. TimeoutException) thus making debugging possible.  Simply un-tick the "break on this exception" when the exception window pops up.

Comment: @Slugart I'm well aware of that. But if I did that at the first place, it was because: a) we are a team of 10, and we all want to skip the same exception b) Some exceptions of the same type but at some other places are not expected and should interrupt the debugging.

Comment: @J4N I know, I share your pain, all our DebuggerStepThrough attributes are useless too.  I just thought it might help.

Comment: @J4N Good news :) There is a public release of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (CTP) available now and it has the workaround fix for the DebuggerNonUserCode issue.

You can see more details on exactly how to use the workaround at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/12/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Good news, I saw the CTP but I didn't know if it was including this fix. It still mean that we have to change all our attributes, right? What is the difference between DebuggerStepThrough and DebuggerNonUserCode now? Also, we often have visual studio using more than 2.5GB of ram, and in those case, it lags as hell, doing a simple "F10" to go to the next line in debug take 1-2 seconds, which makes it unusable. I saw that there has been some memory improvement I hope it will help us.

Comment: @J4N, no need to change your attributes. DebuggerStepThrough and DebuggerNonUserCode are the same in the eyes of the debugger for JMC purposes.

Comment: @John Hi, I just updated VS2015 to the Update2, and I'm a little bit disappointed, I've the `JustMyCode` enabled, a method where the exception is caught and logged, with the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute, but when I encounter this exception, the debugger still stops on the parent method(even if there is no more exception at this point). What should I do to enable the behavior you described?

Comment: @J4N, that is the default behavior. To get the behavior you want, set a reg key by running the following command in cmd.exe:
**reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Debugger\Engine /v AlwaysEnableExceptionCallbacksOutsideMyCode /t REG_DWORD /d 1**

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: It seems to work. Do you know if there is any plan to add a GUI option under Options -> debugging?  maybe you could update your answer with how to activate it, and I will accept it

Comment: No plans to expose the option in the UI. If you would like that option, please make a suggestion on https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @John I don't know if they made an update or something, but some days ago, I was having again the same issue. I tried to execute again the command, but even with stopping/starting visual studio I have my exception popping  within the DebuggerStepThrough methods.

Comment: @J4N no update that I know of. If the setting was overwritten/deleted and you added the registry key with Visual Studio open, you may have to start, stop, and start again for the debug engine to apply the setting if the Hosting Process is on.

Comment: I even restarted the computer to be sure. But in fact I think I found, for some reason, I got the "Just my code" that was disabled. Sorry about that